# Django as S3 proxy

Tags: django, django-admin, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

I extended a ModelAdmin with a custom field "Download file", which is a link to a URL in my Django project, like:

```
http://www.myproject.com/downloads/1
```

There, I want to serve a file which is stored in a S3-bucket. The files in the bucket are not public readable, and the user may not have direct access to it. Now I want to

- avoid that the file has to be loaded in the server memory (these are multi-gb-files)
- avoid to have temp files on the server

The ideal solution would be to let django act as a proxy that streams S3-chunks directly to the user. I use boto, but did not find a possibility to stream the chunks.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than proxying, why not simply redirect?

Use the django view at www.myproject.com/downloads/1 to serve a HTTP Redirect to the S3 storage URL - it's possible to generate time-limited authenticated URLs e.g. see here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Then the client downloads the file directly from S3, but the contents is still secure and access has to come through your Django application

Comment: I wish there were other answers here. I need the same thing except I need to add the header "Content-disposition: attachment".

Comment: @katylavallee I was able to use the redirect method AND add the "Content-Disposition" header by adding this param to the `generate_presigned_url` call: `'ResponseContentDisposition': 'attachment'`

Comment: @DanielKuhlwein Thank you very much! You have saved me the day! =)

Answer (score 20):

Yes, you can use Django as a proxy to stream your S3 files to the user.

1. Generate a standard S3 url for your file.
2. Use the `requests` library to fetch your file in streaming mode.
3. Use Django to serve up the raw stream to the user.

```py
import requests, boto3
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

class MediaDownloadView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        s3 = boto3.resource(
            service_name='s3', aws_access_key_id='XXX_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
            aws_secret_access_key='XXX_AWS_ACCESS_KEY',
        )
        url = s3.meta.client.generate_presigned_url(
            ClientMethod="get_object", ExpiresIn=3600,
            Params={
                "Bucket": 'XXX_BUCKET_NAME',
                "Key": 'XXX_OBJECT_KEY',
            },
        )
        r = requests.get(url=url, stream=True)
        r.raise_for_status()
        response = HttpResponse(r.raw, content_type='audio/mp3')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=music.mp3'
        return response
```