# How to serve the uploaded files only for authenticated users in Django using Amazon S3 and Boto?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto

I have a case like this:

I have a backoffice panel. Authenticated users can upload files to the system. My Django code uploads the files to Amazon S3 server and it becomes public.

Now, what I want is, people who directly writes the url of the image cannot see the files(let's say photos) but the authenticated users can see the files.

Is it possible?

Comment: Here's a way to do it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55158134/336687

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `@login_required` [decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) on the view which shows people the image if they enter the url only if they're logged in. The User Auth section of the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) covers all of this stuff.

Alternatively, you could check whether the user is logged in via request.user in the view, and then not pass the image details in the context to the template.

Or not render parts of the template if there is no user logged in (I think probably the ugliest method)

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    # Do the template stuff
{% endif %}
```

As for limiting access on s3, its a little more complex. You need to make your files non-public in the bucket, then generate urls within Django which have a querystring allowing an authenticated user access to download a particular s3 object with a time limit. Details on that can be found at the [s3 documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth?r=4303). A similar question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7923972/781909) on SO.

Comment: Yes I know about that, but what if somebody tries and finds the public url and access it from the browser?

Comment: What do you mean by finds the public URL? As in of the file on s3? Or via your application?

Comment: As I know, when you upload 'a.jpg' to S3 to a bucket b, its public url is 'http://b.s3.amazonaws.com/a.jpg . So Everybody can see this picture. What I want is, only the authenticated people in my application can see these photos.

Comment: Here's a way to do that

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55158134/336687